# How to bring photos collection data from campaign collection in mongoose?

Tags: express, mongoose, ejs

```
I have 3 collections in mongoose. one is campaign collection that reference to user and other one is photo collection that reference to campaign collection. I can pull the campaigns data based on user but not able fetch photos based on campaigns. Here One user might have many campaigns and each campaign has their own photo collections.

 My models :

**Photo collection:**

var photoSchema = new Schema({
    Name: {type: String},

    Email:  { type: String },

    Photo:  { type: String },
    Description:{type:String},

    PhoneNumber:{type:String},
    CampaignId: { 
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
      ref: 'Campaigns', 
    } 

  });
```

This is campaign collection that reference to user. This is again get reference from photos collection. I want to render photos relating one campaign in gallery. Campaign title is send as params in URL but unable to figure it how to this.

Post route of photos collection :

exports.postEntriesCollection = (req, res) => {

```
Campaign.findOne({Title:req.params.Title}, function(err, campaign) {

let filename = '';


if(!isEmpty(req.files)) {
    let file = req.files.file;
    filename = file.name;
    let uploadDir = './public/PhotoContestUploads/uploads/';
    console.log(filename);
    file.mv(uploadDir+filename, (err) => {
        if (err)
            throw err;
    });
}


const photo = new PhotoEntries({

  Email:req.body.email,
  Name:req.body.name,
  Description:req.body.description,
  Phonenumber:req.body.Phone, 
  CampaignId:campaign._id,
  Photo:`uploads/${filename}`
});
 photo.save().then(post => {

  req.flash('success', { msg: 'Uploaded successfully' });
     res.redirect('#');

 });
});
```

}

```
**campaign collection:**

var campaignSchema = new Schema({
    Campname: {type: String},
     userId: { 
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
      ref: 'User', 
    } 

  });


****To render gallery my route like this :**  I try to pull photos using campaign ID stored in photos collection here :** 

exports.getGallery = (req, res) => {
 PhotoEntries.find({req.CampaignId}, ['Photo'], {sort:{ _id: -1} }, function(err, photos) {
    res.render('admin/gallery', {  photolist : photos }); 
  });
}


I am not able to get gallery of particular campaign instead i am getting all photos relating all campaigns. I want to show only gallery of particular campaign. I have gallery url like this :  /photocontestapp/awesome%20baby%20srija/gallery.How can i achieve this.
```

Comment: I assume `PhotoEnties` is the model of `photoSchema` and `{req.CampaignId}` should be `{CampaignId: req.CampaignId}`, right?

Comment: Yes, Correct  @TheeSritabtim

Comment: In that case you should check that `req.CampaignId` is not `undefined` and is of type `ObjectId` as specified in the schema.

Comment: Okay any way , i will remove that , how can i fetch my gallery photos of particular campaign

Comment: I am saving campaign id into photo schema for referencing

Comment: Your query `PhotoEntries.find({ CampaignId: req.CampaignId })` looks good already, you just have to ensure that `req.CampaignId` is of type `ObjectId`

Comment: yes i checked already and campaign ID is saving in data base in photo collections

Comment: I mean specifically when you want to query it, not when you save it. How dow you get `req.CampaignId` ?

Comment: Campaign.findOne({Title:req.params.Title}, function(err, campaign) {

Comment: I have this in post route

Comment: Could you include that part in your question as well? also the part where you set `req.CampaignId`

Comment: Done added , in above code please check it

Comment: You included the code that shows how you save `PhotoEntries`, which looks fine. We would like more details on how you get from `/photocontestapp/awesome%20baby%20srija/gallery` to `req.CampaignId`

Comment: I just use this to find campaign id from campaiggn collection : 
    Campaign.findOne({Title:req.params.Title}, function(err, campaign) {

Answer (score -1):

From the comments, I assume you haven't set `req.CampaignId` so you should query it and find the campaign first. This should solve your problem.

```
exports.getGallery = (req, res) => {
  Campaign.findOne({ Title: req.params.Title }, function(err, campaign) {
    PhotoEntries.find({ CampaignId: campaign._id }, ['Photo'], {sort:{ _id: -1} }, function(err, photos) {
      res.render('admin/gallery', {  photolist : photos }); 
    });
  });
};
```